# Run Python script at the start

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

i've a Python Web Server (led.py) on home/pi/WebServer on my raspberry.
How can i execute it when raspberry start? I try @reboot sudo Python /home/pi/WebServer but it doesn't work

Comment: What distro  are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.mikeslab.net/?p=176). It should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line in your `/etc/init.d/rc.local`:

```
python /home/pi/WebServer
```

and it will run during startup.

Comment: At the top of the script

Answer (score 0):

Look here for answer : [Cannot get my python script to run on startup/from a shortcut on raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322978/cannot-get-my-python-script-to-run-on-startup-from-a-shortcut-on-raspberry-pi/30323912#30323912)

I did a small example how to run python scripts on boot.